# Copy file option successfully but it is not retaining the version history - Power Automate - MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have used the Copy file option successfully but it is not retaining the version history in the destination. For ex. if I copy Document1 from x library in site collection 1 to y library in site collection 2 it creates version 1.0. Next time if I copy the same file after doing some updates to the file, it replaces the existing file in the destination and the created file still shows version 1.0, instead of version 2.0. Instead of copying it from Flow if I upload the same document directly to the destination library then it creates version 2.0. We need to keep the version history in the destination list. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Copy file]** action in Power Automate doesn't have an option to retain version of the file. However, maybe versions can be retained using **_api/site/CreateCopyJobs** REST API call in Power Automate via **IgnoreVershionHistory** option.

For a detailed example, visit [this article](https://gist.github.com/zplume/21248c3a8a5f840a366722442cf9ee97)

Comment: its good work around, but I can't say this as perfect answer, thank you